# why the bool value doesnt modified by void function？

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    bool check = true;
    while (check) {
        test(check);
        //printf("%d", check);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is my main.c file

and this is my header.c file

```
#include <stdbool.h>
void test(bool check)
{
    while (true)
    {
                if(check){
        check = false;
        break;
                }
    }
}
```

i notice this while im doing the another programm , and it goes inifite loop.
why the check value doesnt change to false?

get a false value and end loop

Comment: C is call-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is pass-by-value, not by-reference.

This means that `test()` gets a copy of the value of the `check` variable's value. It has no way to reach back and change the caller's variable, that the argument is named the same as the variable does not matter.

To fix it, you need to pass the address of the value instead, using pointers:

```
void test(bool *check)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (*check){
            *check = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and then of course you need to explicitly pass the address, in `main()`:

```
int main() {
    bool check = true;
    while (check) {
        test(&check);
        //printf("%d", check);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, it would be cleaner to *return* the new value, instead of passing the pointer.

Comment: thank you for response . but if i try pass that by pointers the error shows up "Access Violation error"

Comment: @huxiuleiwe then you need to understand why you are getting this error. Probably you used pointers incorrectly but it is impossible to know without seeing your pointer code.

Comment: @huxiuleiwe The function call `test(check)` in `main()` needs to be changed to `test(&check)`.

Comment: thank you very much mr unwind and @Ian Abbott. now it works.